# JQuery noUiSlider values return 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

sorry if i wasn't speficly in my topic.
anyway i've problem with my code, some times it returns 0 and i don't know why?
I've tried with many ways and no returns.

Some details:

It returns 0 between 400-1000

There no problem with second point

The problem in first point

I mean 'point' that point i can move it right-left

Code:

HTML:

```
 <div id="slider-range-ow-duo"></div>
```

JS:

```
  var rangeSliderOwD = document.getElementById('slider-range-ow-duo');

noUiSlider.create(rangeSliderOwD, {
  start: [1, 3500],
step: 100,
range: {
  'min': [1],
  'max': [3500]
  },
   connect: true
  });
 rangeSliderOwD.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
  var result = 0;
  var count = 0;
  rangeSliderOwD.value = values[handle];

  for(var i=values[0];i<=values[1];i++){
    for(var j=0;j<globalPriceList.length;j++){
        if((i >= globalPriceList[j][0])&&(i < globalPriceList[j][1])){
            result+=globalPriceList[j][2];
        }
    }
  }
  result=result*1.5;
  $("#f-sr").text(parseInt(values[0]));
  $("#t-sr").text(parseInt(values[1]));
  $("#pric1").text("Price: " + Math.round(result)+ "$");
  var value = values[0];
    if((value>=1)&&(value<=1499)){
        $('#sr-f').attr('src','images/bronze.png');
    } 
    if((value>=1500)&&(value<=1999)){
        $('#sr-f').attr('src','images/silver.png');
    } 
    if((value>=2000)&&(value<=2499)){
        $('#sr-f').attr('src','images/gold.png');
    } 
    if((value>=2500)&&(value<=2999)){
        $('#sr-f').attr('src','images/platinum.png');
    } 
    if((value>=3000)&&(value<=3499)){
        $('#sr-f').attr('src','images/diamond.png');
    } 
    if((value>=3500)&&(value<=3999)){
        $('#sr-f').attr('src','images/master.png');
    } 
    if((value>=4000)&&(value<4350)){
        $('#sr-f').attr('src','images/grandmaster.png');
    }
  var value = values[1];
    if((value>=1)&&(value<=1499)){
        $('#sr-t').attr('src','images/bronze.png');
    } 
    if((value>=1500)&&(value<=1999)){
        $('#sr-t').attr('src','images/silver.png');
    } 
    if((value>=2000)&&(value<=2499)){
        $('#sr-t').attr('src','images/gold.png');
    } 
    if((value>=2500)&&(value<=2999)){
        $('#sr-t').attr('src','images/platinum.png');
    } 
    if((value>=3000)&&(value<=3499)){
        $('#sr-t').attr('src','images/diamond.png');
    } 
    if((value>=3500)&&(value<=3999)){
        $('#sr-t').attr('src','images/master.png');
    } 
    if((value>=4000)&&(value<4350)){
        $('#sr-t').attr('src','images/grandmaster.png');
    }
});
```

GIF shown the problem:
[Click Here](https://gyazo.com/08742a66e9564a2a11334fdf41fe68a4)

Comment: where is your html and add the slider config where you are initializing the slider

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Done.

Comment: may be for some indexes globalPriceList[j][[2] can be empty. try putting console.log where it is adding values to result in forloop and check if it having any values or not.